# Error configuring Weld 2.0 project with tomcat 7 container

Tags: java, tomcat7, cdi, weld

Trying to deploy a war project under tomcat7 and i am facing the following issue / error:

(Only with weld servlet 1.1.12 final i was able to deploy the project)

INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Java\workspace_plataforma_arq.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\educacao_empreendedora\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Alpha1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Jun 11, 2013 4:47:05 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Java\workspace_plataforma_arq.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\educacao_empreendedora\WEB-INF\lib\weld-servlet-2.0.1.Final.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class

POM:

```
<project  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.infosolo</groupId>
    <artifactId>empreed</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Empre</name>
    <description>Empre</description>
    <properties>
        <deltaspike.version>0.4</deltaspike.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId> <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId> 
            <version>0.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WELD CONFIG CDI -->
        <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId> <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId> 
            <version>1.1.12.Final</version> </dependency -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- FIM WELD CONFIG -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>deltaspike-core-api</artifactId>
            <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>deltaspike-core-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>deltaspike-jpa-module-api</artifactId>
            <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>deltaspike-jpa-module-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${deltaspike.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- dependency> <groupId>javax.el</groupId> <artifactId>el-api</artifactId> 
            <version>2.2</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency -->



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <warName>empreend</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/educacaoempreendedora</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Central Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>public</id>
            <name>Public Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>apache</id>
            <name>apache</name>
            <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-oss-public</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>public</id>
            <name>Public Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <organization>
        <name>Infosolo LTDA</name>
        <url>www.infosolo.com.br</url>
    </organization>
</project>
```

Comment: I've seen some other people having issues with Weld Servlet 2.0, have you tried the forums too see if anyone else has solved or asked?

Comment: Yes. It apears that rh guys only want weld running under "WildFly" :-)

Comment: Have you looked at TomEE in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the weld-servlet-2.0.1.Final will not be loaded because it has an offending package javax.el bundled.  Use weld-servlet-2.0.0.SP1 .

Answer (score 4):

Try this exclusion, it worked for me:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```